# Max Memory for the Unibody Macbook Pro 2.8 Ghz

Tags: memory, macbook

I have a Late 2008 Macbook Pro 2.8 Ghz with 4GB of ram, and I'm trying to figure out what the max amount of ram I can install in this machine.

Some places say 6GB, Apple sells 8GB kits for it. I'm confused.

Comment: If the *manufacturer* says "8", what's the confusion?

Comment: The confusion is, the manufacturer sez 8, but the system only supports 6. Derp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the confusion out of the issue. What does Crucial or Kingston say about the memory capacity of the computer?

The manufacturers manual is a snapshot in time, it only reflects what the manufacturer tested, when the manual was being written. They are rarely updated, unless a new version of the computer / motherboard / etc comes out.

Kingston & Crucial are willing to test with newer memory chipsets, etc. So if they say your model will accept more, then it should work.

From Crucial:

Manufacturer Specifications - Apple MacBook Pro 2.8GHz Intel Core 2 Duo (15-inch DDR3) Mid-2009

Number of Slots:
 Slot 1
 Slot 2

*Not to exceed manufacturer supported memory.

Drive Form Factor:   2.5"
Drive Interface:   SATA
Maximum Memory:   8192MB
Slots:   2 (2 banks of 1)
Standard Memory:   4096MB removable
USB Support:   2.x Compliant

Although the memory can be installed one module at a time, the best performance comes from using matched pairs of modules.

Answer (score 1):

It supports up to 8gb ram. It for sure supports 8gb of RAM if apple sells kits for it.